# $X$ set, $Y \subset X$. Is there any relation between the groups $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Sym}(Y)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ denote the group of the bijections on the set $X$, and take $Y \subset X$. Is there any relation between the groups $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Sym}(Y)$?

**Background**. Let $R$ be a division ring; then, either $G:=(R,+)$ and $G^*:=(R \setminus \lbrace0\rbrace,\cdot)$ are groups (with, in particular, the former abelian). By Cayley Theorem, $G \cong \Theta \le \operatorname{Sym}(R)$ and $G^* \cong \Xi \le \operatorname{Sym}(R\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace)$, so that - before asking whether it makes sense to look for relations between $\Theta$ and $\Xi$ - I think we need to firstly address the same question for $\operatorname{Sym}(R)$ and $\operatorname{Sym}(R\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace)$ theirselves.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than the fact that $\operatorname{Sym}(Y)$ sits naturally as a subgroup is $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$?

Comment: No, that's what I need and actually argued, but wasn't sure about. Thanks

Comment: In general there might be several embeddings; for instance, $\mathrm{Sym}(X\sqcup X)$ contains at least 3 copies of $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$: one acting on the left and identity on the right, vice versa, and one acting on both copies. In your specific context, the left action of $R^*$ on $R$ fixes zero, so $R^*$ naturally embeds into the symmetric group of $R$, fixing zero. The right multiplication also defines another such embedding (namely given by the action $r\cdot x=xr^{-1}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\operatorname{Sym}(Y)$ embeds naturally as a subgroup in $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ the following way: Take a bijection $f:Y\to Y$, and extend it to a bijection $f':X\to X$ by $f'(x) = x$ for any $x\in Y^c$. This subgroup is not normal in general.

Comment: To be fussy, it's not normal unless either $|Y|\le 1$ or $Y^c$ is empty :)

Comment: @YCor Sure. Fixed now.

Comment: @Arthur, now I'm aware that any $f \in \operatorname{Sym}(Y)$ can be extended to some $f' \in \operatorname{Sym}(X)$ (the most natural one of which is the $f'$ that you have defined). But actually, as maps, $f' \ne f$ (isn't it?), so it's hard for me to accept a writing like "$f \in \operatorname{Sym}(X)$", necessary to come up to the statement $\operatorname{Sym}(Y) \le \operatorname{Sym}(X)$.

Comment: @Luca You are right. Technichally, the sets $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Sym}(Y)$ are disjoint. However, the embedding in question is so natural that I think this abuse of notation is justified.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.